# How to bootstrap a Laravel command line script?

Tags: php, laravel-5, inversion-of-control

I want try some code in cmd. I need to access to the service container of a full MVC laravel app.

I have create a PHP file in the root directory of application with the following contents:

```
<?php
       require_once __DIR__ . '/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__ . '/bootstrap/app.php';

dd(config('app.locale')); // does not works!
```

However the no service is available. What other should I add to the file to make it working?

Comment: You need to call `$app->bootstrap();` first but why reinvent the wheel? Write a [custom artisan command](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/artisan#writing-commands) and the app will be bootstrapped for you. You will only need to populate the `fire()` method

Comment: @JaviStolz `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::bootstrap() `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bootstrap the app. The simplest way to do this is through the console kernel. This will register providers, facades, etc.

```php
require_once("vendor/autoload.php");
$app = require_once("bootstrap/app.php");

$kernel = $app->make(\Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class);
$kernel->bootstrap();

echo config("app.name");
```

Comment: Many thanks. Sorry, I forgot to mark this as an answer earlier.